# Ansible uncomment line and change string value

Tags: ansible

I've got a line in a config file as follows:

```
# value = False
```

I know you can use lineinfile to remove the '#' as follows:

```
- name: Uncomment parameters
  lineinfile:
    dest: app.conf
    regexp: (?i)^\s*#\s*({{ item }}.*)
    line: \1
    backrefs: yes
  with_items:
    - value
```

I was wonder if there was a way to also change the 'False' to 'True' in the same task or would that require another task? (using replace most likely?)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, unless there is some other logic you want added?

```
- name: Uncomment parameters
  lineinfile:
    dest: app.conf
    regexp: (?i)^\s*#\s*{{ item }}.*
    line: "{{ item }} = True"
    backrefs: yes
  with_items:
  - value
```